# Mysql table definition error

Tags: mysql

I am still getting error around the repeat column.

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'repeat TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, popis TEXT DEFAULT NULL, start DATE ' at line 4**

```
CREATE TABLE akce (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nazev VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  repeat TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  popis TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  start DATE NOT NULL,
  end DATE NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REPEAT` is a MySQL reserved word. Surround it with ` marks to escape it, or rename the column.

Answer (score 0):

`repeat`, `start`, and `end` are reserved words. Always use back quotes( ` ), to surround them, to get them accepted.

Though some words are not mentioned in the reserved words table announced, it would be a better practice avoiding use of reserved words as data identifiers.

***Refer To***:  [***MySQL Reserved Words***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)